# In scikit-learn, does a ConstantKernel have an effect if its value is fixed for Gaussian process regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

In scikit-learn, a `GaussianProcessRegressor` [model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html) takes among its parameters a kernel and the optimizer to be used on its hyperparameters.
I understand that if the optimizer is set to `None` or if the hyperparameters of the kernel are set to `'fixed'` then they cannot be changed.

The default kernel for GPR in scikit-learn is `ConstantKernel(1.0, constant_value_bounds="fixed") * RBF(1.0, length_scale_bounds="fixed")`. I assume that the constant kernel has a purpose here, but based on my understanding it cannot be anything but 1 and thus have no effect.

My question is : is there any practical difference between the default kernel and simply the `RBF(1.0, length_scale_bounds="fixed")` kernel ?

Answer (score 1):

`ConstantKernel(1.0, constant_value_bounds="fixed") * RBF(1.0, length_scale_bounds="fixed")` is not a default kernel in scikit-learn or any other library, but it is widely used so we may treat as default. In GP, we do not treat any kernel as the default (source: [kernel cookbook](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Eduvenaud/cookbook/)).

Coming to your question, the equation of the RBF kernel is the following,

```
    part1 = sigma^2
    part2 = exp(((x1-x2)^2)/l^2)
    RBF(x1, x2) =  part1 * part2
```

Here, `l` is lengthscale and `sigma^2` is variance hyperparameter. Other implementations such as GPy, directly treat `sigma` and `l` as parameters of the kernel. But, scikit-learn chose to do it differently.

In sklearn, `ConstantKernel()` is modeling `part1` and `RBF()` is modeling `part2`.

So, if we used the "fixed" argument in both parts, there is no practical difference, but if they are variable, then they are different as I tried to describe above.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant the default kernel in scikit-learn, not in general. I have just edited my post to make this clearer. So we have the same conclusion ? Given the `'fixed'` parameters, a `RBF(1.0, length_scale_bounds="fixed")` would be equivalent to the default kernel ?

Comment: Yes, you can check this numerically.